# Assert without runtime environment

Tags: c++, c, assert

Is it possible to have some form of assert without a runtime environment? `static_assert` requires a constant expression, and `assert` is part of the C library and thus relies on operating system calls. However let's say that you had no library functions to print anything to the screen, and that you don't have the system calls to make assert work. What's a way of debugging your program?

Comment: You can write your own assert macro / function that send debug strings through UART or SPI.

Comment: debugging messages are important, if you are in an embeded architecture, try to add function which send debug info via serial port for example.

Answer (score 1):

All the `assert` macro does is call `abort()` to deliberately crash the program if its argument evaluates to zero.  If your platform has no `abort` function, you can write one that terminates the program in a suitable way.  Or, if you have `abort` but it's unsuitable, you can write your own customized `assert` macro that does something else.  (Presumably your program has *some* way of producing output, or your question would be much broader than how to make `assert` useful.)

If the reason why you have no system calls is that you're writing a kernel (and thus you're responsible for *implementing* the system calls), note that a kernel's equivalent of an assertion failure is called a [kernel panic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_panic).